# How to call a function after finishing recursive asynchronous jobs in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I use scrapy for scraping this [site](https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=sr_nr_p_6_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1571265031%2Cp_76%3A437878031%2Cp_6%3AA1X6FK5RDHNB96&bbn=1571265031&ie=UTF8&qid=1462897192&rnid=437864031).

I want to save all the sub-categories in an array, then get the corresponding pages (pagination)

---

first step i have

```
def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(start_urls[i], callback=self.get_sous_cat)
```

get_sous_cat is a function which gets all the sub-categories of a site, then starts asynchronously jobs to explore the sub-sub-categories recursively.

```
   def get_sous_cat(self,response):
    #Put all the categgories in a array
    catList = response.css('div.categoryRefinementsSection')
    if (catList):
        for category in catList.css('a::attr(href)').extract():
            category = 'https://www.amazon.fr' + category
            print category
            self.arrayCategories.append(category)
            yield Request(category, callback=self.get_sous_cat)
```

When all the respective request have been sent, I need to call this termination function :

```
def pagination(self,response):
    for i in range(0, len(self.arrayCategories[i])):
        #DO something with each sub-category
```

**I tried this**

```
def start_requests(self):

    yield Request(start_urls[i], callback=self.get_sous_cat)

    for subCat in range(0,len(self.arrayCategories)):
       yield Request(self.arrayCategories[subCat], callback=self.pagination)
```

Comment: You tried "this" and what was the result? How does it differ from your expectations?

Comment: By completely, do you mean when the scrape has finished? It looks like that from your code axample. You could try hooking to the spider_closed signal, see the docs here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-closed. Can you explain more about what your doing in the pagination routine?

Comment: in this link [link] https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A3635788031%2Cp_76%3A437878031%2Cp_6%3AA1X6FK5RDHNB96%2Cn%3A!3635789031%2Cn%3A6356706031&bbn=3635789031&ie=UTF8&qid=1462896936&rnid=3635789031 we have a category with 17 pages, and we have the sub-categories like Repas, what i want to do, is put the url of this page + the url of his sub categories like Repas in a array and, with the pagination function get 17 pages of the category

Comment: @Steve By completely, i mean that we finish to get the url of  all sub-categories of all categories ( some sub-categories have sub-categories too) but Scrape is not finish yet

Comment: i edited my question and i added more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well done, this is a good question! Two small things:

a) use a set instead of an array. This way you won't have duplicates
b) site structure will change once a month/year. You will likely crawl more frequently. Break the spider into two; 1. The one that creates the list of category urls and runs monthly and 2. The one that gets as start_urls the file generated by the first

Now, if you really want to do it the way you do it now, hook the spider_idle signal (see here: [Scrapy: How to manually insert a request from a spider_idle event callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970112/scrapy-how-to-manually-insert-a-request-from-a-spider-idle-event-callback) ). This gets called when there are no further urls to do and allows you to inject more. Set a flag or reset your list at that point so that the second time the spider is idle (after it crawled everything), it doesn't re-inject the same category urls for ever.

If, as it seems in your case, you don't want to do some fancy processing on the urls but just crawl categories before other URLs, this is what Request priority property is for (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-subclasses). Just set it to e.g. 1 for your category URLs and then it will follow those links before it processes any non-category links. This is more efficient since it won't load those category pages twice as your current implementation would do.

Comment: Excellent answer, that's two new things I know about scrapy now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not "recursion", it's asynchronous jobs. What you need is a global counter (protected by a Lock) and if 0, do your completion :

```
from threading import Lock

class JobCounter(object):
   def __init__(self, completion_callback, *args, **kwargs):
      self.c = 0
      self.l = Lock()
      self.completion = (completion_callback, args, kwargs)
   def __iadd__(self, n):
      b = false
      with self.l:
         self.c += n
         if self.c <= 0:
            b = true
      if b:
         f, args, kwargs = self.completion
         f(*args, **kwargs)
   def __isub__(self, n):
      self.__iadd__(-n)
```

each time you launch a job, do `counter += 1`

each time a job finishes, do `counter -= 1`

NOTE : this does the completion in the thread of the last calling job. If you want to do it in a particular thread, use a Condition instead of a Lock, and do `notify()` instead of the call.

Comment: Not sure you need a lock with Scrapy :-) It's most of it Twisted/single threaded.