# Call parse method in spider_closed method

Tags: scrapy

I want to call parse method that is called by scrapy itself when the scraper starts. Is it possible to call it manually after the scraping is complete.

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def parse(self, response):
        # something here

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        # CALL PARSE METHOD AGAIN
```

Comment: It doesn't seem likely as there's no response object to pass to parse(). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to restart the scraper after it has completed scraping

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) which describes running scrapy from a script.

Comment: If you want to restart a crawl, have a look at `spider_idle` signal, used in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16971379/2572383)

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @PawneetSingh, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, [@StevenAlmeroth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971379) using `spider_idle` is probably what you need.

Here's an example spider restarting twice:

```
import scrapy

class IdleRestartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "idlerestart"
    restarts = 0
    max_restarts = 2

    start_urls = ['http://httpbin.org/html']

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(IdleRestartSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.idle, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
        return spider

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info("Got response %r" % response)
        yield scrapy.Request('http://httpbin.org/get?restarts=%d' % self.restarts,
                             callback=self.parse_response)

    def parse_response(self, response):
        self.logger.info("Got response %r" % response)

    def idle(self):
        self.logger.info("Spider is idle: %d restarts left" % (
            self.max_restarts - self.restarts))
        if self.restarts < self.max_restarts:
            self.logger.info("Spider is restarting")
            self.restarts += 1
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(
                scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0],
                               dont_filter=True),
                self)
```

And here's the output using `scrapy runspider` (with scrapy 1.1.0)

```
$ scrapy runspider idlerestart.py 
2016-05-19 10:49:18 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2016-05-19 10:49:18 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-05-19 10:49:18 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-05-19 10:49:18 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://httpbin.org/html> (referer: None)
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [idlerestart] INFO: Got response <200 http://httpbin.org/html>
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://httpbin.org/get?restarts=0> (referer: http://httpbin.org/html)
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [idlerestart] INFO: Got response <200 http://httpbin.org/get?restarts=0>
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [idlerestart] INFO: Spider is idle: 2 restarts left
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [idlerestart] INFO: Spider is restarting
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://httpbin.org/html> (referer: None)
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [idlerestart] INFO: Got response <200 http://httpbin.org/html>
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://httpbin.org/get?restarts=1> (referer: http://httpbin.org/html)
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [idlerestart] INFO: Got response <200 http://httpbin.org/get?restarts=1>
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [idlerestart] INFO: Spider is idle: 1 restarts left
2016-05-19 10:49:19 [idlerestart] INFO: Spider is restarting
2016-05-19 10:49:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://httpbin.org/html> (referer: None)
2016-05-19 10:49:20 [idlerestart] INFO: Got response <200 http://httpbin.org/html>
2016-05-19 10:49:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://httpbin.org/get?restarts=2> (referer: http://httpbin.org/html)
2016-05-19 10:49:20 [idlerestart] INFO: Got response <200 http://httpbin.org/get?restarts=2>
2016-05-19 10:49:20 [idlerestart] INFO: Spider is idle: 0 restarts left
2016-05-19 10:49:20 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-05-19 10:49:20 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1410,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 13542,
 'downloader/response_count': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 6,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 19, 8, 49, 20, 438174),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 18,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 19, 8, 49, 18, 865649)}
2016-05-19 10:49:20 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Make sure you add necessary `dont_filter=True` arguments where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass control to parse function by using this

```
return super(YourSpider, self).parse(response)
```