# Create Scrapy never ending spider

Tags: python, scrapy, pika

I've created a scrapy library [scrapy-mq-redis](https://github.com/rdcprojects/scrapy-mq-redis) and want to make the spiders never ending. I've used spider_idle signal handler to stop it from closing (picked it from upstream library).

Is there a way to access scheduler in this function so that I can call next_request function and process further incoming requests or maybe even more start_urls?

Let me know if further clarity is required.

**EDIT**: The possible duplicate question has a custom create_request method. 
For my library, I need to send acknowledgements for the messages to RabbitMQ via the exact same channel that received it. That is why there is a listener in scheduler / queue for processed requests (response_received). So, I specifically have to use the scheduler to create requests.

The alternative would be to have another listener in my spider for response_received, which would mean that broadcasts for all requests/responses will be sent to two methods and then I have to determine if the message was received from the particular process and then accordingly send ack. This adds extra processing and duplication of the same process in two different modules.

I hope this clarifies my requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy: How to manually insert a request from a spider\_idle event callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970112/scrapy-how-to-manually-insert-a-request-from-a-spider-idle-event-callback)

Comment: @PawelMiech Have added more details about my question and how its different from the other one.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the scheduler is available in spider as below:

`self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.next_request()`

I added listener in spider as below:

`self.crawler.signals.connect(self.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)`

And the callback is as below:

```
def spider_idle(self):
    self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.next_request()
    raise DontCloseSpider
```

This keeps the spider alive and also looks for new requests that may have been added to the queue.