# struggling with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and I struggle a little with a special case.

Here is the scenario :

I want to scrap a website where there is a list of books.

**httpx://...bookshop.../archive** is the page where all the 10 firsts books are listed.

Then I want to get the informations (name, date, author) of all the books in the list. I have to go on another page for each books:

**httpx://...bookshop.../book/{random_string}**

So there is two types of request :

- One for refreshing the list of books.
- Another one for getting the book informations.

But some books can be added to the list at anytime.
So I would like to refresh the list every minutes.
and I also want to delay all the request by 5 seconds.

Here my basic solution, but it only works for one "loop" :

First I set the delay in **settings.py** :

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
```

then the code of my spider :

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class bookshopScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bookshop"
    url = "httpx://...bookshop.../archive"
    history = []
    last_refresh = 0

    def start_requests(self):
        self.last_refresh = time.time()
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[3]

        if page == 'archive':
            return self.parse_archive(response)
        else:
            return self.parse_book(response)


    def parse_archive(self, response):
        links = response.css('SOME CSS ').extract()

        for link in links:
            if link not in self.history:
                self.history.append(link)
                yield scrapy.Request(url="httpx://...bookshop.../book/" + link, callback=self.parse)

            if len(self.history) > 10:
                n = len(self.history) - 10
                self.history = history[-n:]

    def parse_book(self, response):
        """
        Load Item
        """
```

Now I would like to do something like :

```
if(time.time() > self.last_refresh + 80):
        self.last_refresh = time.time()
        return scrapy.Request(url=self.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

But I really don't know how to implement this.

PS : I want the same instance of scrapy to run all the time without stopping.

Comment: I think you can use this question's answer to build a scraper that creates a new request whenever it becomes `idle` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970112/scrapy-how-to-manually-insert-a-request-from-a-spider-idle-event-callback